# ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (26000,1) into shape (26000) for sklearn preprocessing StandardScaler

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, scikit-learn

I am working on a `numpy array X` that has multiple features (or columns).

I am trying to standardize the first feature (column) of the dataset:

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
sc = StandardScaler()

X[:,0] = sc.fit_transform(X[:,0].reshape(-1,1))
```

and I get this error:

```
ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (26000,1) into shape (26000)
```

if I remove `reshape(-1,1)` then I get this error:

```
Reshape your data either using array.reshape(-1, 1) if your data has a single feature or array.reshape(1, -1) if it contains a single sample.
```

How can I tackle this problem?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you tried using (1, -1)?

Comment: `or array.reshape(1, -1) if it contains a single sample.`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will split this answer to two parts. First understanding the input to the StandardScaler's fit_tansform function, and second understanding the output.

If you follow the StandardScaler documentation on the [fit_transform](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.StandardScaler.html#sklearn.preprocessing.StandardScaler.fit_transform) function, it says:

> Parameters: X array-like of shape (n_samples, n_features)Input samples.

> Returns X_newndarray array of shape (n_samples, n_features_new)

Understanding the Input:

Here, when you do X[:,0], you are getting your entire column, but in one row. Here's an example on a random 3x2 array:

```
import numpy as np
X = np.random.random_sample((3,2))*10
print(X)
print(X[:,0])
print(X[:,0].shape)
```

gives

```
[[3.5782437  6.12481959]
 [9.2333248  8.49628361]
 [8.56447626 5.24588392]]

[3.5782437  9.2333248  8.56447626]

(3,)
```

Here lies our first issue. The StandardScaler expects a 2D array where the rows are each sample, and the columns are the features, in this case 1 feature. Therefore, we need a (3x1) 2D array, but we have a (3,) 1D array. This causes the error you get without reshaping. To convert our 1D array to the shape the function expects, we use [reshape](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.reshape.html#numpy.ndarray.reshape). The function expects a **shape** parameter. We want a (3x1) shape, therefore, use reshape(-1,1) (the -1 indicates that numpy will infer we want all elements).
To confirm this:

```
print(X[:,0].reshape(-1,1))
```

gives

```
[[9.31648164]
 [6.74048286]
 [7.57667118]]
```

Now, we are ready to input this to StandardScaler's fit_transform.
Second, the output of fit_transform:
Let's look at the shape of its output:

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
sc = StandardScaler()
print(sc.fit_transform(X[:,0].reshape(-1,1)))
print(sc.fit_transform(X[:,0].reshape(-1,1)).shape)
```

gives

```
[[ 1.34073239]
 [-1.06001668]
 [-0.28071571]]
(3, 1)
```

We are getting a 3x1 2D array when X[:,0] is actually a (3,) 1D array. We want to flatten this array back to a 1D array. There are multiple ways to do this. We could use reshape again by giving one value to indicate a 1D array, and a -1 means all values:

```
temp = sc.fit_transform(X[:,0].reshape(-1,1)).reshape(-1)
print(temp)
print(temp.shape)
```

gives

```
[ 1.34073239 -1.06001668 -0.28071571]
(3,)
```

This means that `X[:,0] = sc.fit_transform(X[:,0].reshape(-1,1)).reshape(-1)` will work.

Using [ravel](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ravel.html#numpy.ravel) or [flatten](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.flatten.html#numpy.ndarray.flatten) work as well.

Comment: It was a very comprehensive and thorough answer thank you!

Answer (score 1):

`sc.fit_transform(X[:,0].reshape(-1,1))` is a 2D array with shape `(26000,1)` and you cannot assign it to a `1D` placeholder `X[:,0]` with shape `(26000)`.

Try to flatten the fit when assign back:

```
X[:,0] = sc.fit_transform(X[:,0].reshape(-1,1)).ravel()
```